# Compiler wants ";" - I don't know why (in C)

Tags: c, compiler-errors

Working on a project Euler problem (#10), I've an interesting compile error. My compiler tells me I need a semicolon. The exact error is `49: ';' expected`.

Now I know this is not unusual with C code, but the problem is I've triple checked all semicolons and parentheses and brackets, and none are missing. Not even in loops. Chances are I'm just missing it.

HOWEVER
The compiler tells me `49: ';' expected` - but the code on line 49 is just one bracket (`{`).

Would anyone have any insight into what might be wrong here?

Code is as follows:

```
// this is a program to find the sum of all primes below 2 million
// uses the Seive of Eratosthenes

#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    long int sum = 0;
    long int s = 2000000; // size of array
    long int i;           // 'for' loops
    long int n;           // number to test
    long int a;           // prime checker
    long int multiples;

    long int* array; // define pointer for calloc int array
    // calloc the array
    array = (int*)calloc(s, sizeof(int)); // allocates 2,000,000 spots (s) of
                                          // size "int" to array "array"
    // set all array values equal to 1
    for (i = 0; i < 2000000; i++) {
        array[i] = 1;
    }

    /*
    VALUES IN ARRAY
    The values of the array indicates whether number-
    (0) IS PRIME
    (1) UNTESTED
    (2) IS COMPOSITE
    */

    // implement prime finder
    for (n = 0; n < 2000000; n++) {
        if (array[n] == 0) // IF n IS PRIME
        {
            multiples = n;
            multiples += n;

            while (multiples < 2000000) {
                array[multiples] = 2;
                multiples += n;
            }
        } else
            (array[n] == 2) // IF n IS COMPOSITE (is a multiple)
            { // THIS IS LINE 49
                continue;
            }
        else(array[n] == 1) // UNTESTED
        {
            for (a = 2; a < n; a++) // double checks for composites
            {
                // tests factors
                if (n % a == 0) {
                    printf("ERROR");
                    goto end;
                }
            }

            array[n] = 0;
            multiples = n;
            multiples += n;

            while (multiples < 2000000) {
                array[multiples] = 2;
                multiples += n;
            }
        }
    }

    // read array and sum primes
    for (n = 0; n < 2000000; n++) {
        if (array[n] == 0) // IF n IS PRIME
        {
            sum += n;
        } else
            (array[n] == 2) // IF n IS COMPOSITE
            {
                continue;
            }
        else(array[n] == 1) // IF n MAY/MAY NOT BE PRIME
        {
            printf("ERROR");
            goto end;
        }
    }

    printf("The sum of all primes < 2,000,000 is... %ld!\n", sum);

end:
    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Almost none of the posted code is event relevant. Make sure to reduce the test-case to a minimal form (in which case many problems become self-evident).

Comment: bro, do you even `else if`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change the `else` to `else if` and you are fine.

And do that with **all** the `else`.

Answer (score 0):

You're really missing is some `if`s to go with your `else`s:

```
if( array[n] == 0) // IF n IS PRIME
{
    sum += n;
}
else if( array[n] == 2) // IF n IS COMPOSITE
{
    continue;
}
else if( array[n] == 1) // IF n MAY/MAY NOT BE PRIME
{
    printf("ERROR");
    goto end;
}
```

It's pretty easy to confuse a compiler like this, and when you do, some of its error messages can get hard to understand.

Answer (score 0):

```
else( array[n] == 2) // IF n IS COMPOSITE (is a multiple)
    {                 //THIS IS LINE 49
```

`else` doesn't take a condition. The `else` should be `else if`.

The compiler's syntax recovery tries to suggest the simplest change that would result in a syntactically valid program. Often the suggested change doesn't make much sense. In this case, adding a `;` after the `else` would turn the following `( array[n] == 2)` into the beginning of an *expression statement* (which would have to be followed by another semicolon).

If your code produces a syntax error message, the best approach is often to ignore the suggestion it makes and just look at the line it refers to *and the line(s) preceding it*, and figure out what's wrong with the syntax at that point. Then fix the error and recompile.